# Is $\left(\mathrm{Im}\left(T\right)\right)^⊥\subseteq \ker T^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $T:V\rightarrow V$
How to prove that $\left(\mathrm{Im}\left(T\right)\right)^⊥\subseteq \ker T^*$?

I wrote this so far:
Let $v\in \left(\mathrm{Im}\left(T\right)\right)^⊥$.
So, for all $T(a)$  $\in $  $\left(\mathrm{Im}\left(T\right)\right), \langle v,T(a) \rangle = 0$, and therefore $\langle T^*(v),a \rangle = 0$.

What am I missing? How to go from here?

Comment: *so for all $T(a)$  $\in $  $\left(Im\left(T\right)\right)$, <$v$,$T(a)$ > = $0$.

Comment: What is $a$?${}{}$

Comment: sorry,a is some vector in V

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$ is arbitrary, $T^{*}(v)=0$. Thus, $v\in\ker T^{*}$. Hence, $(\mathrm{Im}T)^\perp\subseteq\ker T^{*}$. (You could show that the two spaces are equal by demontrating that $(\mathrm{Im}T)^\perp\supseteq\ker T^{*}$. This is an interesting exercise.)

Comment: how you prove that T*(v) = 0?

Comment: @user2637293 It is by definition of the inner product on $V$.

Comment: @user2637293 If the inner product between two non-zero vectors vanishes, then the two vectors are orthogonal. However, since $a$ is arbitrary - and $T^{*}(v)$ is not necessarily non-zero, and the inner product vanishes, $T^{*}(v)=0$.

Comment: @user2637293 Yes, for **non-zero** vectors. Do you know if $T^{*}(v)$ is non-zero for all $v$? **No!** Hence, since since $a$ is arbitrary - and $T^∗(v)$ is not necessarily non-zero, and the inner product vanishes, $T^∗(v)=0$.

Comment: i'm still little bit confused. if <$T*(a)$,$v$> = $0$, then we have 3 possible situations: $1$ they orthogoal. $2$, $v$ is $0$, and $3$ ,$T*(a)$ is $0$. right?

Comment: @user2637293 1) wouldn't work since we don't know if both $T^{*}(v)$ and $a$ are non-zero. Consider $\langle T^{*}v,a\rangle$. 2) would work if $a$ was **not** arbitrary, which it is. Hence, 3) is the only option; i.e., $T^{*}(v)=0$.

Comment: OK..i try now to prove the other side as you say. i wrote this:
i took some arbitrary vector v in ketT*, so T*(v) = 0 , and vector u in V.

so by the inner product, i get <Tu,v> = 0 and here i stuck again like in the first side you helped me

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

$$(im T)^{\perp}=\{ v | \forall a (Ta,y)=0\}$$
and so for $v \in (im T)^{\perp}$, $(a,T^* v)=0$ for all $a$, but this implies (your in a innner product space right ?) that $T^* v=0$ and so, $v \in ker T^*$. In fact the two spaces are equal.

Comment: why its implies that T∗v=0?

Comment: In an inner product space $(x,x)=0$ implies $x=0$. In general, a paring $(,)$ is non degenerate if $(x,y)=0$ for all $x$ implies $y=0$.